# Does Microsoft BizSpark come with full MSDN benefits?

Tags: msdn, bizspark

was wondering if there are anyone else here that has signed up with the same program and could give me some advise. I've signed on to the Microsoft BizSpark program sometime earlier a month or two ago, and has activated the MSDN subscription that came with the program.

The subscriber and keys section of the site was accessible after I signed in to the MSDN portal.

I wanted to subscribe to the MSDN Magazine as well, and was directed to sign on via a designated link on the Manage My Subscription page. The said link could not be found. Looking at the help page, there was supposed to be this Online Concierge link that I can click on to get live help. Again, it was supposed to be on the Manage My Subscription page, but was nowhere to be found.

Is the MSDN subscription provided via the BizSpark program supposed to be "crippled" (provided only partially)? Also, do we have an option to get discs delivered instead of having only downloads, similar to the retail MSDN subscriptions?

Edit: It's strange - I wonder if the MSDN folks read StackOverflow, because I just signed into my subscriber downloads area and I found a new link to "MSDN Magazine Subscription" under the "Subscription Benefits" box on the Subscription Home page of MSDN.

I filled in the request form and submitted it successfully, not sure what's supposed to happen now 'cause the submission page did not provide much detail. Fingers crossed! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC I don't think it's a full subscription to MSDN, it's just access to MSDN Subscriber Downloads - I've certainly not got the option for the magazine, and don't get any discs.

Comment: Hmm... That's what I was afraid of. The BizSpark FAQ was kind of misleading though, as it talks about MSDN Premium, and how the Online Concierge is part of it. But apparently at no point did they explicitly states that you are getting MSDN Premium - just the software that usually comes with it.

Comment: If you ping them an email they might hook you up with the magazine, but I doubt they'll do discs for you. I don't think I can really complain about the amount of stuff they give you though :-)

Comment: Because of the way tax laws work, if they give you physical media on DVDs, they have to charge sales tax, and things get complicated. Even Enterprise customers these days don't get media unless they're willing to pay more.

Comment: I still get discs in work on our "normal" MSDN, but perhaps the tax isn't an issue in the UK.

Comment: In my country, both the 'downloads only' and 'downloads + DVDs' subscriptions cost the same, though they do "throw in an extra free month" if you select 'downloads only'.

Answer (score 19):

This is Cliff, @ Microsoft

We tweaked MSDN Premium to create the  BizSpark subscription.

We removed the internal use licenses and the media mailings, and reduced the technical support incidents.

We added the standard (full) version of VSTS, which isn't available in any MSDN subscription, and we added unlimited production licenses for Windows Server, SQL Server, Biztalk, Sharepoint and Systems Center.

We didn't intentionally turn off the magazine and concierge, though. We are checking on this and will correct if there's no no good reason for it to be turned off.

Cliff

Comment: Hi Cliff, as indicated in my original post edit, I was able to find the Subscription link again some time later. The first time I submitted it the process seemed incomplete. Sometime later I tried it again and this time it prompted me for an address and payment information. The nominal amount for delivery was deducted from my bank account so I believe the feature is working again. Now I'm just waiting for the magazine to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question specifically to MS (via email) and have not gotten a good answer yet.  The helpdesk people apparently cannot understand English.  I will report when I get a good answer.

EDIT

I called MSDN today and they said I just get downloads - no physical media.

I have found that the MSDN site has errors a lot.  I also find the whole site extremely disorganized and non-intuitive.  (it has been like that for years - even as a user at a company with bulk licenses)

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/d/4/4d41081a-d8d9-407a-9bae-5127e6e931ca/BizSpark%20Startup%20Program%20Guide.pdf

Comment: Well, at least it is a bit more organized now than it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at both accounts and here is what they come with:

## Visual Studio Team Suite (VSTS) with MSDN Premium:

- Subscriber Downloads and Product Keys - Download software and get product keys.
- Microsoft E-learning - Take advantage of free Microsoft E-learning courses to hone your skills.
- MSDN Forums/Managed Newsgroups - Get expert answers to your technical questions within two business days. (English only)
- Support Incidents - For your toughest technical questions, contact Microsoft Support.
- MSDN Magazine Subscription - Sign up each year to stay informed of Microsoft development technologies and trends.
- Online Concierge Chat - Do you need guidance finding the answers you are looking for, or assistance with a non-technical question?

## Bizspark:

- Subscriber Downloads and Product Keys
- Support Incidents
- MSDN Magazine Subscription

The only thing I'm really missing from Bizspark is MSDN Forums/Managed Newsgroups.
It would really make sense for Microsoft to add them though as Bizspark is about helping companies to get started and the Forums are very good for that.

Comment: Is that different from the publicly accessible forum at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories? Anyway, I usually just come here (StackOverflow) 'cos the community is pretty great too, and you get people from all backgrounds to comment.